# Recursive function not ending on a return statement?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm going through eloquent javascript & this recursive function has me stumped, I understand most of it.

```
function findSolution(target) {
  function find(current, history) {
    if (current == target) {
      return history;
    } else if (current > target) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5)`) ||
             find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);
    }
  }
  return find(1, "1");
}

console.log(findSolution(24));
// → (((1 * 3) + 5) * 3)
```

The part that absolutely baffles me is in the case when the current > target, if I console log the current and it exceeds the target numerous times but then continues with the recursion trying a different combination, why is it the function doesn't return null & end there?

Comment: Because of your `||` below.

Comment: Because according to the `else` part there are two paths that can be searched. If the first one resolves to `null` then still the second path could give something else.

Comment: btw, you could omit `else` and go on with simple `if`, because `return` ends the function. if not returned, the execution goesd on and a single `if` would be sufficient.

Comment: See this is the part that still confuses me I understand that if the left hand side of the operator evaluates to a number larger than the target it will go to the right hand side, but if I console log this I can see this happening & then the right hand side also returns a number larger than the target, but the statement will start again from a different set of instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Because of this:

```
return find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5)`) ||
            find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);
```

When the function called at the left part of the OR returns a null, it evaluates to false, so the second part is evaluated, and the function is called again